# Is there a way in go to convert a []byte slice to an io.Reader?

Tags: io, go, byte

I have just started with go and was wondering, if it is possible to convert an []byte slice to an io.Reader. The Otherway around is possible as shown in ioutil.ReadAll.
If not is it possible to use code.google.com/p/go.net/html.Tokenizer somehow with a byte slice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes: [bytes.NewBuffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer)

io.Reader Example:

http://play.golang.org/p/P0VbE8UFpC

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // A Buffer can turn a string or a []byte into an io.Reader.
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("R29waGVycyBydWxlIQ=="))
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, buf)
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, dec)
}
```

Comment: What's different from `bytes.NewReader`?

Comment: @FredHors I know it's been a while but I was also curious about this, so I looked into the source code. [Taken from a comment in the source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bytes/reader.go#L16) `// Unlike a Buffer, a Reader is read-only and supports seeking.`. I suppose the question should be "what's your use case?"

Answer (score 8):

You can use the NewReader in the bytes package:

```
in := bytes.NewReader(b []byte)
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader

Comment: What's different from `bytes.NewBuffer`?

Comment: (putting this here, too) I know it's been a while but I was also curious about this, so I looked into the source code. [Taken from a comment in the source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bytes/reader.go#L16) // Unlike a Buffer, a Reader is read-only and supports seeking.. I suppose the question should be "what's your use case?"